# Odoo product search to_date is not correct

Tags: odoo, product

I am using Odoo V12 and trying to query products at a certain date, but this query does not return the right values. Does anyone have an idea what could be the problem?

```
        products = self.env['product.product'].\
            search([('type', '=', 'product'), ('qty_available', '!=', 0)]).\
            with_context(dict(to_date=self.date, company_owned=True,
                              create=False, edit=False))
```

Comment: Maybe I do something wrong, but I get ther error: Invalid field 'to_date' in leaf.

Comment: I was looking up how Inventory Valuation and Inventory Report works at certain date and I found that you can add to_date parameter to the context. I want to query information about the products at a certain date, like qty_at_date. I am trying to reproduce basically what Inventory Valuation does with some additions to it.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to search on field that is not exist in database.
search query only runs if field exist in database. 
that means you can not pass compute store = false fields in search query.
compute field works only if store = True